# delete a Record from an Array

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript

I need to deleta a record from an Array

Basically I am assigning a RecordSet(a department table) to my Array.
I want to delete a department Record from this Array.
How can I do this.

I am new to VB script and I appreciate if you can give me code how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript doesn't support push and pop operations on an array.  You have three options:

1. Iterate the array while building a new array, skipping the value you want to delete.
2. Use the Scripting.Dictionary object rather than an array.  It supports Add/Delete operations.
3. Utilize a utility class to make working with arrays a little easier.  [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/20210728074610/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032800-1.shtml) has a good example. (https://web.archive.org/web/20210728074610/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/032800-1.shtml)